# Unable to get the Socks Proxy working Golang applications

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am running a golang application on my local laptop, which connects with the Service APIs from a kubernetes cluster. To allow the communication between my laptop and Service APIs on Kubernetes Cluster, I have setup the Socks5 proxy and Able to connect with all services over CURL command.

But I am unable to set same proxy in the Golang application. I have tried various options already

1. Settings env vars - tried setting these 3 at OS level, App level but it did not work

   - http_proxy
   - https_proxy
   - all_proxy
2. I am running on Ubuntu Desktop 20.X, so I tried setting Socks proxy at OS Network level as well. All other apps using proxy, but golang isnt picking that up.
3. I tried setting the http.transport level configs too, but it didnt helped.

```
func InsecureTLSTransport() *http.Transport {

    // START - Only for Proxy - Dev Mode.
    var dialer, err = proxy.SOCKS5("socks5", "<IP:port>", nil, proxy.Direct)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "can't connect to the proxy:", err)
    }
    return &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
        Dial: dialer.Dial,
    }
}
```

I want the socks5 Proxy to be used by my golang app at runtime. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `tcp` instead of `socks5` in the network parameter.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
)

func main() {
    d, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", "<IP:port>", nil, proxy.Direct) // <-- here
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    c, err := d.Dial("tcp", "https://google.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()
}
```